# Через цикл foreach вывести таблицу?

Tags: php

Как через цикл foreach вывести таблицу, в которой в ячейках будут находится input и иметь индивидуальное имя?

Проблема в том, что в строках таблицы мне надо иметь индивидуальные имена.

```
<form method="POST" action="zow.php">
     <table border="1" width="20%" cellpadding="10">
    <?foreach($result as $request):?>  
    <tr>
<td><?=$request['name']?> <?=$request['surname']?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?= $a += 1?>"/><input type="hidden"  name="<?= $b += 50?>" value="<?$timestamp = time();?><?= date('d/m/Y', $timestamp) . $request['id']?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?= $a += 1?>"/><input type="hidden"  name="<?= $c += 50?>" value="<?$timestamp = time()+ 86400 * 1;?><?= date('d/m/Y', $timestamp) . $request['id']?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?= $a += 1?>"/><input type="hidden"  name="<?= $d += 50?>" value="<?$timestamp = time() + 86400 * 2;?><?= date('d/m/Y', $timestamp) . $request['id']?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?= $a += 1?>"/><input type="hidden"  name="<?= $e += 50?>" value="<?$timestamp = time() + 86400 * 3;?><?= date('d/m/Y', $timestamp) . $request['id']?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?= $a += 1?>"/><input type="hidden"  name="<?= $f += 50?>" value="<?$timestamp = time() + 86400 * 4;?><?= date('d/m/Y', $timestamp) . $request['id']?>"/></td>
    </tr>
   <?endforeach?>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо $a - выводи primary key твоей таблицы. Если для каждого значения есть несколько инпутов - выводи как-то типа: `'inputSpecialWord_' . $primary`.

PS: вообще не понял откуда берутся переменные $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f ...

PPS: вообще не понял сути скрипта =)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте сделать по примеру моей таблицы!

```
<?php
include('bd.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$bookname=$row['bookname'];
$id=$row['id'];
$avter=$row['avter'];
$upload=$row['upload'];
?>

<div style="float:left;width:500;border:solid 4px red;">
<h4>Name:<?php echo $bookname;?></h4>

<h4>автер - <?php echo $avter;?></h4>

<a href='books/<?php echo $upload;?>'>read</a>
<form action='download.php' method="get">
<input type=text name=filename value='http://subdomain.localhost/books/<?php echo $upload;?>'>
<input type='submit' value='Скачать'>
</form>

</div>

<?php
}
?>
```